# How to combine two selects with same value but not the same INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, inner-join

I have to need a project school, a site like ebay
with bid.
I have to make a select who select

- the name of the seller
- the name of the last "customer" (bid)

BUT THE PROBLEM is that there two value was in the same table, so for access to the value I need to make 2 select with different INNER JOIN (look the diag for understand)

[image: diag of website]

I have made two selects but I don't understand how to make a single select.

```
    SELECT nom AS nameSeller
    FROM ENCHERES e
    INNER JOIN  ARTICLES_VENDUS  ac ON ac.no_article = e.no_article 
    INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS u ON u.no_utilisateur = ac.no_utilisateur
    WHERE nom_article LIKE '%ta%'
    
    SELECT nom AS nameCustomer
    FROM ENCHERES e
    INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS u ON e.no_utilisateur = u.no_utilisateur
    WHERE e.no_utilisateur= 57
```

**what i have with two select**

First select

| nameCustomer |
| --- |
| john |

Second select

| nameSeller |
| --- |
| bryan |

**What i want in one select**

| nameSeller | nameCustomer |
| --- | --- |
| bryan | john |

**Fil to the script to create table and bdd**

```
-- Script de création de la base de données ENCHERES
--   type :      SQL Server 2012
--

CREATE DATABASE BDDTEST2
GO
USE BDDTEST2
GO

CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (
    no_categorie   INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    libelle        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES ADD constraint categorie_pk PRIMARY KEY (no_categorie)

CREATE TABLE ENCHERES (
    no_utilisateur   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_article       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date_enchere     datetime NOT NULL,
    montant_enchere  INTEGER NOT NULL

)

ALTER TABLE ENCHERES ADD constraint enchere_pk PRIMARY KEY (no_utilisateur, no_article)

CREATE TABLE RETRAITS (
    no_article         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rue              VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    code_postal      VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ville            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE RETRAITS ADD constraint retrait_pk PRIMARY KEY  (no_article)

CREATE TABLE UTILISATEURS (
    no_utilisateur   INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    pseudo           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    nom              VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    prenom           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    telephone        VARCHAR(15),
    rue              VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    code_postal      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ville            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    mot_de_passe     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    credit           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    administrateur   bit NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE UTILISATEURS ADD constraint utilisateur_pk PRIMARY KEY (no_utilisateur)


CREATE TABLE ARTICLES_VENDUS (
    no_article                    INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    nom_article                   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description                   VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    date_debut_encheres           DATE NOT NULL,
    date_fin_encheres             DATE NOT NULL,
    prix_initial                  INTEGER,
    prix_vente                    INTEGER,
    no_utilisateur                INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_categorie                  INTEGER NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE ARTICLES_VENDUS ADD constraint articles_vendus_pk PRIMARY KEY (no_article)

ALTER TABLE ARTICLES_VENDUS
    ADD CONSTRAINT encheres_utilisateur_fk FOREIGN KEY ( no_utilisateur ) 
    REFERENCES UTILISATEURS ( no_utilisateur )
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE no action 

ALTER TABLE ENCHERES
    ADD CONSTRAINT encheres_articles_vendus_fk FOREIGN KEY ( no_article )
        REFERENCES ARTICLES_VENDUS ( no_article )
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE no action 

ALTER TABLE RETRAITS
    ADD CONSTRAINT retraits_articles_vendus_fk FOREIGN KEY ( no_article )
        REFERENCES ARTICLES_VENDUS ( no_article )
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE no action 

ALTER TABLE ARTICLES_VENDUS
    ADD CONSTRAINT articles_vendus_categories_fk FOREIGN KEY ( no_categorie )
        REFERENCES CATEGORIES ( no_categorie )
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE no action 

ALTER TABLE ARTICLES_VENDUS
    ADD CONSTRAINT ventes_utilisateur_fk FOREIGN KEY ( no_utilisateur )
        REFERENCES UTILISATEURS ( no_utilisateur )
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE no action
```

**Link to insert value**

```
USE BDDTEST2
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTILISATEURS]
           ([pseudo]
           ,[nom]
           ,[prenom]
           ,[email]
           ,[telephone]
           ,[rue]
           ,[code_postal]
           ,[ville]
           ,[mot_de_passe]
           ,[credit]
           ,[administrateur])
     VALUES
           ('zorg'
           ,'john'
           ,'john'
           ,'j@k.c'
           ,'15454'
           ,'hjh'
           ,'hkk'
           ,'hjgjh'
           ,'hjkjg'
           ,0
           ,0 )
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTILISATEURS]
           ([pseudo]
           ,[nom]
           ,[prenom]
           ,[email]
           ,[telephone]
           ,[rue]
           ,[code_postal]
           ,[ville]
           ,[mot_de_passe]
           ,[credit]
           ,[administrateur])
     VALUES
           ('zorg'
           ,'bryan'
           ,'bryan'
           ,'j@k.c'
           ,'15454'
           ,'hjh'
           ,'hkk'
           ,'hjgjh'
           ,'hjkjg'
           ,0
           ,0 )
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CATEGORIES]
           ([libelle])
     VALUES
           ('enfant')
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[ARTICLES_VENDUS]
           ([nom_article]
           ,[description]
           ,[date_debut_encheres]
           ,[date_fin_encheres]
           ,[prix_initial]
           ,[prix_vente]
           ,[no_utilisateur]
           ,[no_categorie])
     VALUES
           ('Jouet',
           'desc',
           '2002-01-01',
           '2003-01-01',
           0,
           0,
           2,
           1)
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[ENCHERES]
           ([no_utilisateur]
           ,[no_article]
           ,[date_enchere]
           ,[montant_enchere])
     VALUES
           (1,
          1,
           '2002-02-02',
           50)
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: Sample data, and expected results (in a consumable format) will help us help you.

Comment: Please post the code to create the table and insert queries to load the data into the table or post the table data as tabular markdown.

Comment: That isn't sample data that's just a couple of columns.

Comment: Sorry i just post the script for create and insert i don't understand very well

Comment: You can use the same table more than once in the same query, by giving it a different alias each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CROSS APPLY to pull back the buyer for each of the sellers.  Consider the following:

```
 SELECT u.nom AS nameSeller, x.nom nameBuyer
    FROM ENCHERES e
    INNER JOIN  ARTICLES_VENDUS  ac ON ac.no_article = e.no_article 
    INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS u ON u.no_utilisateur = ac.no_utilisateur
CROSS APPLY(
        select u.nom 
        from  UTILISATEURS u WHERE  u.no_utilisateur = e.no_utilisateur
    ) X
```

Comment: How is that different from a second inner join on UTILISATEURS? just alias it to `X` instead of `u`...

Answer (score 0):

- lead will move the current row to 1 place above
- Union will join data in single column
- you need to have a common factor like date for `order by` clause

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9127/sql-server-window-functions-lead-and-lag/

```
with main_data as (

    SELECT nom AS nameSeller,
    'Seller' as category_seller_or_customer
    FROM ENCHERES e
    INNER JOIN  ARTICLES_VENDUS  ac ON ac.no_article = e.no_article 
    INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS u ON u.no_utilisateur = ac.no_utilisateur
    WHERE nom_article LIKE '%ta%'

    union

    SELECT nom AS nameCustomer,
   'Customer' as category_seller_or_customer
    FROM ENCHERES e
    INNER JOIN UTILISATEURS u ON e.no_utilisateur = u.no_utilisateur
    WHERE e.no_utilisateur= 57
),
getting_seller_and_buyer AS (

select 
*,
 lead(category_seller_or_customer) 
 over(order by 
       [some date factor or something that both have in common]
     ) as current_seller_or_customer

from main_data
)

select 

*,
case 
when category = 'Seller' then current_seller_or_customer else end as seller,

case 
when category = 'Customer' then current_seller_or_customer else end as customer

from 

getting_seller_and_buyer
```